# QGIS How do I set the spatial resolution of a raster?

Tags: pixel, raster, qgis, resampling, envi

I have some files that started out as .hdf files and I have converted them to TIFFs after some destriping.  These images have no spatial reference and have been defaulted to 1 pixel = 1 degree.  This comes out to 111,319.419 meters per pixel.  Can I change the pixel size to something more manageable.
This imagery is non-georeferenced hyperspectral imagery.  I can calculate the true pixel size given the elevation and sensor field of view (which I have).

Comment: did you find an answer? I have the same struggle now.